# How to programmatically add and get rich text using a TdxRichEditControl?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

*DevExpress* doesn't provide docs about "How to programmatically add and get rich text using a `TdxRichEditControl`".
Or Any suggestion to Embedded Full text Editor in my program? I am on Delphi Seattle.

**My Situation:**

I am creating a program on which the user need rich text editing (like Bold, Italic, Underlining, Font Size, Font family, Paragraph Aligning). So I've putted a `DBRichEdit` that load a model of text on which the user will make changes.
So I need to take this model text to the `TdxRichEditControl` to apply the changes and back it again to the `DBRichEdit` to save it in the database.

Comment: Recommendation questions are off topic here. And in any case, why would expect a good recommendation without specifying requirements.

Comment: This might help you with the dev express control. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97GaF1kgqPM I find it hard to believe it comes without documentation.

Comment: Thanks, for reponding 
about the link i've already seen it , they don't provide a settext and gettext methods.

Comment: You haven't done enough research. And the question is off topic.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T552683/how-to-programmatically-insert-formatted-text-in-tdxricheditcontrol) for a starter. There are several other q/a on the topic.

Comment: I have an outdated DEvExpress Package 15.2.2 which don't allow document.insert, i am downlowding the last version. thanks @Tom

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just insert portions of text into the control, this is some code I used to use for copying from one DevExpress RichEdit to another.. You might be able to adapt it to copy from another source (warning - it's a few years old):

```
procedure AppendToRichEdit(const Source, Dest: TcxRichEdit) ;
var
  RTFStream: TEditStream;
  Stream : TMemoryStream;

  function EditStreamReader(dwCookie: DWORD; pBuff: Pointer; cb: LongInt; pcb: PLongInt): DWORD; stdcall;
  begin
    Result := $0000;
    try
      pcb^ := TStream(dwCookie).Read(pBuff^, cb);
    except
      Result := $FFFF;
    end;
  end;

begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Source.Lines.SaveToStream(Stream) ;
    Stream.Position := 0;
    RTFStream.dwCookie := DWORD(Stream) ;
    RTFStream.dwError := $0000;
    RTFStream.pfnCallback := @EditStreamReader;
    Dest.InnerControl.Perform(EM_STREAMIN, SFF_SELECTION or SF_RTF or SFF_PLAINRTF, LPARAM(@RTFStream)) ;
    if RTFStream.dwError <> $0000 then
      raise Exception.Create('Error appending RTF data.') ;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave i already solve the problem by switching to  newer version of DevExpress which supports inserting and Getting Text from TdxRichEditControl. 
TdxRichEditControl.Document.InsertRTFtext();
TdxRichEditControl.Document.GetRTFtext();